# Update Data in Array in React and Redux When Clicked

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a problem on updating the `productCode` in TextField when click of the button. I need to update the `productCode` when a product has no errors and must get its new `productCode` coming from `saveProductResponse`. **The `saveProductResponse` is the result of products with no errors.** The `saveProductResponse` has a field called `name`.
You get its middle letters to filter to get the `productCode` ad to match the `products` `productCode` and after when you match it, you replace it with its new `productCode`. I think you have to filter in the reducer in `appConstants.SAVE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:`

[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-added-array-of-object-inside-another-aray-in-react-forked-4imm7?file=/src/data/index.js:978-982)

**Expected Product Code to Display**

```
ABCDO
FF
GG
```

**CODE**

```
export const getProductCode = (code) => {
  return (
    code.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "").split("_")[1] ||
    code.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "").split("_")[0] ||
    ""
  );
};
```

Comment: What are you needing to update the `productCode` to in the reducer? The data in the save product action payload seems to match what is in the products state already. What am I missing here? If there is a match on `productCode` are you wanting to replace the entire "image" object in the `productImages` array?

Comment: @DrewReese. Good point Drew. Can you make two versions? First just change `productCode` on formik TextField, is this possible since redux is connected to formik? and the second one on the reducer itself.

Comment: @DrewReese. You always get the updated productCode from the `saveProductResponse`

Comment: @DrewReese.`savedProductResponse` has a field called `name`. you can get its `productCode` by using the `getProductCode()` I have implemented. and then you compare it to `products`  productCode so you can access it.  in `products`, you have `productImages` which you will compare vs action.payload if it is there. then you'll be able to change its `productCode` on its products

Comment: So in `saveProductResponse` you've objects with different product codes, like `"ABCDO"` for image `"01_AA_BBB.jpg"`. And when save success is dispatched, the product code is `"AA"` from the file name. You are just wanting this save success object to be added to the `"AA"` products image array?

Comment: @DrewReese. No. rename the `productCode` in `products` from `AA` to `ABCDO`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then something in your CSB needs to consume the `saveProductResponse` object that has the new `productCode` values to pass in the `saveProduct` action so the store can match the current `productCode` so it can be replaced with the new one from the response. Does this make sense?

Comment: @DrewReese. Yes. That's right

Comment: @DrewReese. First, you'll get the old `productCode` throught the field `name` in `savedProductResponse` by using the function `getProductCode` and you'll filter through the `products` array and identify which `productCode` matches the `name`. After that you'll change `productCode` in `products` with the `productCode` from `savedProductResponse`. Nevermind the action.payload.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239414/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-joseph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an API response of corrected `productCode` values that need to be updated in state:

```
[
  {
    newProductCode: "ABCDO",
    oldProductCode: "AA"
  },
  {
    newProductCode: "DQDESS",
    oldProductCode: "EE"
  }
]
```

You can reduce over this array, and for each "update" check if the state contains a product with the corresponding matching `oldProduceCode`, and if it does, shallow copy the `products` array and update the specific product by also shallow copying it, otherwise save the current product and state and move on to the next.

```
case appConstants.SAVE_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
  return saveProductResponse.reduce((state, current) => {
    const shouldUpdate = state.products.some(
      (product) => product.productCode === current.oldProductCode
    );

    if (!shouldUpdate) return state;

    return {
      ...state,
      products: state.products.map((product) =>
        product.productCode === current.oldProductCode
          ? {
              ...product,
              productCode: current.newProductCode
            }
          : product
      )
    };
  }, state);
```